# Make Select Tag Dynamic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have hardcoded the tour_id of my Tour table, how can I make this dynamic?

```
(select_tag 'tournament_id',options_from_collection_for_select(Tournament.all.where(:tour_id => 1)
```

Comment: You will need to give a bit more context of what you are trying to do. Are you trying to have a select drop down with every record in Tournament as an option?

Comment: No only tournaments pertain to the specific tour

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correct your question.

Model

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tournaments
end

class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tour
end
```

Controller (something like this)

....

```
@tour = Tour.includes(:tournaments).find(1)
```

In views

```
(select_tag 'tournament_id',options_from_collection_for_select(@tour.tournaments, ...)
```

Whatever, `Tournament.all.where(:tour_id => 1)` is not rails way. Use rails associations at different practice (more info here [rails associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html))

```
@tour = Tour.find(1)
@tour.tournaments # all tournaments where tour_id = 1 (tour has_many tournaments)
```